# Django. Iterate by models in dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Status(models.Model):

    CHOISES = (
        ('new', 'New'),
        ('in_progress', 'InProgress'),
        .....
    )

    status_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
        choices=CHOISES,
        primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.status_type)


class Task(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

this is part of my view, which return dictionary with keys, based by `status` model:

```
    all_tasks = Task.objects.select_related('status').order_by('status')
    tasks = {status: list(tasks)
         for status, tasks
         in itertools.groupby(all_tasks, lambda x: x.status)
    }
```

Here is part of dictionary which views function return:

```
{<Status: new>: [<Task: Task object>, <Task: Task object>],
 <Status: in_progress>: [<Task: Task object>,<Task: Task object>],...}
```

I need to group all `tasks` models in template by 5 `status` columns.
So I use this call:

```
    {% for item in tasks.new %}
        {{ item.name }}
    {% endfor %}
```

it doesnt work, because I cant get value from my dictionary, by `status` object name.
The question is how I can iterate by `status` object from dict keys, in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what point there is in having a Status model just to store one field. Why not keep that in Task, with the choices defined there?

Nevertheless, you could fix your immediate problem by grouping by `x.status.status`, to use the actual charfield value rather than its containing model.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. But one thing, it will be `x.status.status_type`